# How to integrate Android Beacon Library in my project?

Tags: ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I found this Android Beacon Library in the net, and i found it quite good. But I want to integrate the open source project in my app with some modification in the code so as to display the alert on beacon detection and some other scenarios. 
Actually i am new bee to android, so if anyone can help me out how to integrate the modified code in the app?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it is certainly possible to modify the code of the [Android iBeacon Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/), it is not necessary to make any modifications "so as to display the alert on beacon detection" because this ability is present out of the box.  Making modifications to a library and then using it in a custom project is also a pretty big hill to climb for somebody new to Android development.  Before attempting to do this all at once I would first do the following in order:

1. Learn how to build a [Hello World Android app](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) and run it on your phone.
2. Learn to use [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html).
3. Build and run the [sample application](https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/ibeacon-reference-android) for the library.
4. Make a new app from scratch that uses an unmodified version of the library in binary form to detect iBeacons and display an alert.
5. Learn to the [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/learn) command line build tool and Gradle wrapper
6. Build an unmodified copy of the library source code from the command line with the command `./gradlew release`
7. Use the newly created binary release from (6) in your custom project from (4).

Once you have done all of the above, you can try making modifications to the library source code and getting these modifications to work in your project.

**EDIT:** The library mentioned above has been replaced by the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) with a reference app [here.](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference)

Comment: Hi David, I am not able to build the sample app for the library that you mentioned in step 3. Its saying beacon library is missing!

Comment: There are lots of steps here, so it is probably better to open a new question for this and attach a screenshot of any error you are getting.

Comment: Hey, I have posted a new question for this and here is the url for it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037678/how-to-build-the-sample-project-for-android-library-for-beacon

Comment: @davidgyoung Link is broken for sample beacon app.

Comment: Updated links at bottom.