# How to Build the sample project for Android library for Beacon?

Tags: ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I am trying to build the following sample project provided by the Radius Networks for integrating beacon in Android. The link for the project follows:
[sample project](https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/ibeacon-reference-android)

But the problem is that I am not able to build the project. Please explain the steps to do so.
Thanks in advance.

Note - I am using Eclipse IDE with ADT plugin for building the app.
The error says - "Android Beacon Library is missing".

Comment: What IDE and version are you using for Android development?  What steps have you tried to build it?

Comment: I was using Eclipse IDE with ADT plugin latest version for mac.
I imported the project in the ide, and build it. But it was showing some errors in class files.
So I right clicked the project name, and navigated to its properties, there it was showing error in Android beacon library.(Not Found)

Comment: links are not working !

Answer (score 2):

When using Eclipse, you need to have the Android iBeacon Library imported as a separate library project in the IDE.  Once this is done, you must point your project that uses the library (or the sample project in your case) at this library project.

First, download the Android iBeacon Library in the tar.gz format for Eclipse.  The download page is here:  http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/download.html

Once you have that, follow the full instructions on configuring the library with your project  here:  http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/configure.html